# R - Add column to a dataframe with value between

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I've looked at different trends here but could not find the solution for my problem.

I have the following datasets:

```
Dataset A
phrase  start   end
1   105.476 107.315
2   107.408 109.443
3   110.889 112.482
4   112.557 113.625


Dataset B onsets
105.568
105.981
106.117
106.347
106.646
107.149
107.666
107.827
107.976
108.128
108.31
108.472
111.015
111.199
111.36
111.538
111.72
111.901
112.259
112.44
112.606
112.748
112.901
113.046
```

I would like to create Dataset C which would include a column with the corresponding "Phrase" value in each entry of Dataset B. This means that if the "onset" value is between the value from "start" and "end" of "1", it will indicate "1" in the new row

Example of what I want (DatasetC):

```
Phrase  onsets
1   105.568
1   105.981
1   106.117
1   106.347
1   106.646
1   107.149
1   107.666
2   107.827
2   107.976
2   108.128
2   108.31
2   108.472
3   111.015
3   111.199
3   111.36
3   111.538
3   111.72
3   111.901
3   112.259
3   112.44
etc...
```

I was trying the `merge` or the `match` function, but I could not figure out how to do what I need.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can use a [rolling join](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/06/understanding-data-table-rolling-joins/) from `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
setkey(dt_a, start)
setkey(dt_b, onsets)

dt_b[dt_a, roll = T]
dt_c  <- dt_a[dt_b, roll = T][
    , .(phrase, start)
]
setnames(dt_c, "start", "onsets")

head(dt_c)
#    phrase  onsets
# 1:      1 105.568
# 2:      1 105.981
# 3:      1 106.117
# 4:      1 106.347
# 5:      1 106.646
# 6:      1 107.149
```

Data used:

```r
dt_a  <- fread("phrase  start   end
1   105.476 107.315
2   107.408 109.443
3   110.889 112.482
4   112.557 113.625")

dt_b  <- fread("onsets
105.568
105.981
106.117
106.347
106.646
107.149
107.666
107.827
107.976
108.128
108.31
108.472
111.015
111.199
111.36
111.538
111.72
111.901
112.259
112.44
112.606
112.748
112.901
113.046")
```

**Edit:** updated column names.

**Edit 2: If onset times are not guaranteed to be between start and end**

I said "in this case" above because all your `onset` times are between a `start` and `end`, so we can cheat a little by just checking which start time precedes them. If this is not guaranteed you can add a little logic to check:

```r
# Check that they are actually between
setkey(dt_c, phrase)
setkey(dt_a, phrase)

dt_d  <- dt_c[dt_a][, between := between(onsets, start, end)][]

head(dt_d)
#    phrase  onsets   start     end between
# 1:      1 105.568 105.476 107.315    TRUE
# 2:      1 105.981 105.476 107.315    TRUE
# 3:      1 106.117 105.476 107.315    TRUE
# 4:      1 106.347 105.476 107.315    TRUE
# 5:      1 106.646 105.476 107.315    TRUE
# 6:      1 107.149 105.476 107.315    TRUE
```